# Validates uniqueness in a one-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I have an Album model and Track model. I want to make sure that the name of each track on the album they belong to are unique. I tried using this validation in my `Track` model

`validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, scope: :album_id`

but get the error: `Unknown validator: 'ScopeValidator'`

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tracks

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :album

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, scope: :album_id
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to scope the uniqueness, not put it as a separate argument.

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :album

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :album_id }
end
```

Comment: That returns the error: `undefined method 'validate_uniqueness_of' for #<Class:0x007fa9f239a028>`

Comment: It returns an error because it's missing an 's', the method is: `validates_uniqueness_of`